# If a woman converts, marries, and divorces -- how is she identified in her next ketubah?

Tags: marriage, wedding, conversion-to-judaism, divorce, legal-documents

If a woman converts, marries, and divorces -- how is she identified in her next ketubah? *Matrachta* (divorcee) or *Giyorta* (convert-ess)? Does it matter? Is there a convention which term is used for her? Is it her call?

Comment: I think you mean "matrachta" (or "metarachta") - מתרכתא.

Answer (score 4):

[The book חוקת הגר](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/19148283) (about which and about whose author, **warning**, I know nothing) writes (on page 22):

> גיורת שנתגרשה ורוצה להנשא שנית, יש לכתוב בכתובתה גיורתא דא שלא נשכח ייחוסה, ואין כבר צורך לכתוב מתרכתא דא כי בגיורת יודעים שהיא אסורה לכהן.‏

Or, in my own free translation:

> In the case of a female convert who was divorced and wants to remarry, one should write in her *k'suva* "גיורתא דא" so we do not forget her lineage, and then there's no need to write "מתרכתא דא", for everyone knows a convert can't marry a *kohen*.

He directs the reader to a footnote (16), which [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=UsQRAQAAIAAJ) is not letting me see.

Answer (score 0):

My own intuition is to write divorcee, as the convert status is implied in her being plonit bat Avraham Avinu.

Comment: What if her father's name is unkown or actually is Avraham Avinu?